# Conditional Formatting with lots of data

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Anyway, I have a table in Google Spreadsheets that has a set of rows which each contain a name (Column A) and two Yes or No values (Columns G and H).
I would like a way to conditionally format the rows. I have been trying to learn the formatting but I feel this is well out of my league. The way I would like it all to be formatted is only in Column A. If G says "Yes" and H is empty, then yellow. If G says "Yes" and H says "No", red. If G says "Yes" and H says "Yes", green.

If it helps, here is a chart:

```
G    H

Y    --    Yellow
Y    N     Red
Y    Y     Green
```

An explanation of how it all works would also be much appreciated but if you only have the solution on how to do it, I will gladly take that.

Comment: It could be blank or "No".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**METHOD 1** - Conditional Formatting Only

The easiest way to do this, using Conditional Formatting is as follows:

Select "Format >> Conditional Formatting":

[image]

These IF statements will be used color the cells Yellow, Red, and Green, respectively.

```
=IF(AND(G2="Yes",H2=""),"True")
=IF(AND(G2="Yes",H2="NO"),"True")
=IF(AND(G2="Yes",H2="YES"),"True")
```

[image]

**METHOD 2** - New Column, using f(x), and Conditional Formatting

The code used to generate the text "Yellow," "Red," and "Green" is as follows (broken up in 2 lines only for easier readability):

```
=IF(AND(B2="Yes",C2=""), "Yellow",IF(AND(B2="Yes",C2="No"), "Red",
IF(AND(B2="Yes",C2="Yes"), "Green")))
```

[image]

This is a nested IF statement that will examine your "Yes"/"No"/null column cells. This statement looks for the conditions you specified and returns either "Yellow," "Red," or "Green" in a separate column.

Since your IF statement will output either "Yellow," "Red," or "Green," all you'll have to do is set your Conditional Formatting to look for these words and color the cell accordingly.

[image]

A great resource to learn more is the [Google spreadsheet function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

I've got it for you. It can be made using the conditional formatting in Google Sheet.

A Screen Shot attached
[image: Screen Cap]

Right click your cell A, apply conditional formatting
Just apply it across your range in column A1:A500 something
and choose the "Format cells if..." and choose custom formula

```
(Just click Add another rule after each one so you don't have to repeat the range)

=IF(AND(G60="Yes",H60=""),"True") //Change the color to Yellow 
=IF(AND(G60="Yes",H60="No"),"True") // Change the color to red
=IF(AND(G60="Yes",H60="Yes"),"True") // Change the color to green
```

You will have 3 rules of conditional formating
replace G60 and H60 with the starting row number

Edit ------------------ Forgot to add the explanation

The formula

```
IF(AND(G60="Yes",H60=""),"True")
```

"IF" is to check IF something is this or not. I added the "AND" so that we could put in 2 condition, since we need both conditions to be satisfied. and therefore the formula above in written form would be

IF(IF) BOTH(AND) G60 and H60 is "Yes" and "Empty" respectively, then it is True. So it will become the color I chose.

There might be another way to write the codes but this works :)